How to properly compare the excecution time of several algorithms?
Background
The problems starts from here...
I tried to compare several sorting algorithms to measure the execution time but as I understood I messed up a lot of things :)
The task
At this moment my target is to compare the execution time of several sorting algorithms and collect some statistics for arrays of different sizes
Lets say I have 4 different algorithms and now I need to measure their execution time on 3 randomly generated int arrays with different sizes
Some noticed problems from my previous question:


missed branch prediction. Branch prediction can make a huge difference in how code performs




Have a lot of source codes which prevents some optimizations




Discussing performance when optimizations are disabled is pointless




running both benchmarks from the same process is questionable




cold/hot cache




how/when the OS decides to actually do dynamic allocation


I read some materials today about each of these problems and found some solutions:

As I understand I don't have really control on this because it is something in processor (I read that I can translate if/else into something very ugly to prevent this but I will not do that type of things)

If it is very important I think it will not be a big problem to have all stuff just in main.c (but I really prefer to have functions in different locations because it is very easy for to maintain separate little files than one big file)

I'm using CLion and I found how to add optimization flag set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3) (correct me if I'm wrong)

If it really required then I can write completely different *.c files for each algorithm (but I think that it will be very hard to fairly compare all algorithms because each of them will be executed on different arrays. I think it is not a big problem if I'm allowed to read array from some file so I can prepare some files with numbers and then parse it into array and run tests)

If I understand correctly I just need to run same test several time again and again (correct me if it is not as easy as I read)

I can't understand how to handle this problem. May be trying to define array in stack of function and hope that it will not be overflowed :)


May be there are a lot of another problems I don't know... Is there any proper way to handle all of these problems or handle maximum count of problems?
May be someone has a prepared testing template for these cases?
I will be very glad if someone will be able to provide some code with assuming that all algorithms are already written
Here is some (may be) useful info:

OS: Windows 10

Editor: CLion

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(Test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3)

add_executable(Test main.c
        sorting-functions/bubble_sort/bubble_sort.c
        sorting-functions/bubble_sort/bubble_sort.h
        utils/swap/swap.c
        utils/swap/swap.h
        utils/print_arr/print_arr.c
        utils/print_arr/print_arr.h
        sorting-functions/bubble_sort_2/bubble_sort_2.c
        sorting-functions/bubble_sort_2/bubble_sort_2.h
        utils/copy_arr/copy_arr.c
        utils/copy_arr/copy_arr.h
)



If you need more info please just ask me and I will provide

This question needs much more focus (as opposed to the other one linked). There is too many thing to untangle and que question is not clear either. You should certainly post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or split it in specific independent (standalone) parts. Note that previous stack overflow post can provide partial answers to some points.

I advise you to read famous posts like Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array? talking about branch prediction, and also Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? for micro-benchmarking. Please note that there are faster algorithms than bubble sort (which is very inefficient in nearly-all cases). This includes sorting networks, merge sort, quick sort, radix sort, etc.

@JérômeRichard Thank you for the links I will check them. If you need more details then please say yo me which details I missed and I will add them to the e question. I can't split this question into smaller ones because my task is to benchmark 4 sorting algorithms on different size of array. I just need from someone with experience in benchmarking in C to help me make benchmarking in my case properly. I need it to my scientific paper work - so I can't messed up with this :) And I'm aware of another sorting algorithms I just need to benchmark them

AFAIK, in scientific papers, people often measure properties of the algorithm and not much the execution time. One reason is that the execution time is dependent of the target machine. One specific code C1 can be faster than another one C2 a CPU1 and C1 can be also slower than C2 on CPU2. Branch-less code can be great on some platform and bad on others. Micro-optimization is platform-dependent. Branch-prediction is a complex topic : this is a field of research on its own.

One critical parameter to consider in sorting benchmark (especially in a research paper) is data distribution. You can find some information in the cppcon of Andrei Alexandrescu. IDK if he submitted a research paper about this since. I am pretty sure you can find similar approaches in state of the art sorting-related papers (which is generally a good idea to read so to submit one).

Also please note that there are tools to do benchmarks written by compiler engineers&researchers but AFAIK they target C++ and not C code. They can defeat common compiler optimizations and bad benchmarking setups. It might still applies to your use-case.

@JérômeRichard You are completely right and I understand all of this things but in my work I had to make "Empirical analysis" which means to run and measure the time. And again thanks for links they are very useful!



missed branch prediction. Branch prediction can make a huge difference in how code performs




As I understand I don't have really control on this because it is something in processor (I read that I can translate if/else into something very ugly to prevent this but I will not do that type of things)


The compiler might try to remove unnecessary branches when it can spot them, but writing branch-free code is mainly a manual way of optimizing code. The way of doing it is to enable all relevant optimizations, then run your code in a disassembler for the target (https://godbolt.org/ is awesome for such practices). Then you will look for conditional branch instructions.
For example if you have something like bool something; ... if(something) b *= 2; you could perhaps manually optimize it as b = b + b*something; to remove the branch. That is, in case something is set to true we get b = b + b*1 which is mathematically equivalent to b *= 2, otherwise we get b = b + b*0 which is the same as leaving b untouched. If we did this correct the compiler will generate some multiplication instruction that is always executed, but no conditional branch.



Have a lot of source codes which prevents some optimizations




If it is very important I think it will not be a big problem to have all stuff just in main.c (but I really prefer to have functions in different locations because it is very easy for to maintain separate little files than one big file)


I'm not really sure what this refers to.
But in general, functions and file scope variables with external linkage (not static) prevent the compiler from doing certain optimizations like inlining or assumptions about where a variabled is accessed etc. It's already good practice from a program design point of view to reduce the scope of functions and variables as much as possible, but as it turns out this also helps performance a lot.
So just dropping everything in main.c won't improve the situation a lot unless you also add static.



Discussing performance when optimizations are disabled is pointless




I'm using CLion and I found how to add optimization flag set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3) (correct me if I'm wrong)


I don't know CLion, but -O3 is the correct option to turn on all optimizations when using gcc-like compilers (gcc, clang, icc). There may also be various target-specific options which will help optimal code generation further.



running both benchmarks from the same process is questionable
cold/hot cache
how/when the OS decides to actually do dynamic allocation


All of these are related - there are many reason for why you shouldn't run two different benchmarks from the same executable.
Cold/hot cache is one. Basically the cold/hot thing can be explained as the first benchmarking test doing all the heavy lifting by exporting the test data into cache. And then the second test won't need to do that. Cache memory impact on performance is always tricky and not easily observable. In general you need to be an expert on the specific target hardware to tell how it works there. There might be dummy code for "warming up the cache" for one particular target.
But that's not all. When you run both tests in the same executable, there might be intermingling optimizations between the two tests, mixing them together on the machine code level. Or instruction re-ordering. The first test might leave stuff pre-calculated for the second test to just go fetch.
Another subtle thing on hosted non-realtime OS is that context switches could happen at any moment. The scheduler runs your process within the time slice assigned to it. Now if you run 2 tests, they might get hit unfairly by context switches in the middle of benchmarking. The amount of crap running in the background will affect the test. It might be overall more fair if both tests are running with the same environment prerequisites.
You may or may not be able to do stuff like sleep(0) just before starting the clock, to yield the process' remaining time slice and have it come back with a new one at the point you start the measurement. This is OS-specific though.
Then there's the mentioned issue with dynamic allocation, where at an OS level the actual allocation by malloc isn't carried out until the point when that memory is actually used. This can be avoided by doing a volatile write access of that memory in advance.

Overall, just because you have the code in the same project, you can still use it to generate two different executables by using #ifdef and then linking it twice. And in general run the same test lots of times, to minimize the impact on external stuff like context switching.

Thank you very much for very detailed answer! I will try to implement all your advises and will add all files and details in question directly. The first thing which I want to ask is what you mean by "run the same test lots of times"? You mean to wrap it with some loop or you mean to run whole program again and again?

@EzioMercer Both! Use a whole lot of iterations and run the program several times.

Can I use the batch files to automate whole program running again and again or it will be the same as some loop inside the program?
